# Change WCF Service Binding From basichttp to nettcp

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding, basichttpbinding

What is the easiest way of changing the binding of a WCF service from basichttp to nettcp? Surely you don't have to edit the file manually as there is just too much scope for error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the WCF Service Configuration Editor if you want to avoid errors introduced with manual editing.

Comment: Thanks I've now used that. Now when I try and add a service reference to a new client it fails. I am now using the address net.tcp://localhost:8734/.......... rather than http://...........

Comment: Add Service Reference only works for HTTP endpoints, I think. You'd need to use the Configuration Editor to amend the .config files client-side to match the binding you're using on your service.

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit *some* file. It depends on how you define your binding. If you defined it via config, you'll need to change it (from `<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" ...>` to `<endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" ...>`). If you define it via code, you'll need to change the sourcfe code (from `new BasicHttpBinding()` to `new NetTcpBinding()`). Besides this change, that should be it (provided that the service has a base address for the net.tcp protocol as well).